# jquery page reset on php form submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

So I am making a small quiz app that shows one question at a time, in order to move on to the next question you have to answer the current one correctly, and you have as many tries as it takes you...The quiz works perfectly. When you have answered the last question correctly, a form is displayed and it asks you to fill out some information so that the "quizzer" can send you a gift...The submission of this form is done via php, I did plan on implement JQuery/AJAX but right now I am just testing out the DB connectivity and other functions so i kept it simple...the problem I am having is that when I hit submit the page automatically gets refreshed showing the first question again and not outputting anything from my php script..I am not really sure what kind of code I could include to help anyone solve this, as I think it is a more theoretical problem, but let me know if you want me to post more...

Thanks in advance for any help, it is greatly appreciated!

```
<form action"/index.php" method="POST">
        Congratulations! You passed! Please enter in your email address and we will send you something cool!<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of you form?

Comment: Save if somenone finished the quiz in the session?

Comment: could you show the code as well...!

Comment: I'd have that last form submit go to a different page, say `/finished.php`.

Comment: What is the value of the `action` attribute of the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

If the page submits and posts back to itself, the form is going to reset by design.  You have to add code that detects the postback and if "True" then repopulate the form with the postback values to give the appearance of data persistance.

Havne't used PHP in a long time, but in .net you would detect a postback by calling:

....If IsPostBack Then....

When you do a postback, the entire page reloads, so that is going to fire your Javascript code again. 
To avoid that, you should encapsulate just the form with AJAX to submit just the form so that the rest of the page doesn't post back (including the javascript).
Hope this gives you some direction.

Or... you can change
     
to post to a different file (like /index2.php) and that way you don't have to worry about postbacks or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the post data on the same index.php page, like doing:

```
if(isset($_POST) AND !empty($_POST)) {
   var_dump($_POST);
}
```

This might help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, but with jQuery Mobile.  I have implemented this on the form submit but all I need to do refresh the query results:

```
onClick="window.location.reload(true)"
```

This is basically a page refresh more than anything but might point you on the direction you need as well.